# Redux resets after dispatching an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

so I've been working on this small cinema app and I'm facing a weird bug where every time I try to log in to access the home page it doesn't redirect and then the redux store gets reset, but when I commented `useEffect` in the `HomePage.js` component It worked and also when I tried to `conosole.log(action.payload)` in another reducer file for the movies I got the payload from the `AuthReducer` so I don't know what's the problem, is it with my whole redux setup or because I'm using the render method in my ProtecdedRoute.js

AuthSaga.js

```
function* loginUserSaga({ payload }) {
  yield delay(1500);
  yield put(LoginUserSuccessAction(payload));
}

export default function* AuthSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.LOGIN_USER, loginUserSaga);
}
```

protectedRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect, useLocation } from 'react-router';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: '/login',
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  const renderComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component />
      </Layout>
    );
  };
  return <Route {...rest} render={renderComponent} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Routes.js

```
const Routes = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
  console.log(isLoggedIn);
  return (
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute path="/" exact component={Home} layout={Layout} />
      <AuthRoute path="/login" exact component={Login} layout={AuthLayout} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

AuthReducer

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log(payload)
  switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.LOGIN_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    }
    case actionTypes.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        userName: payload.userName,
        token: `${payload.password}${payload.userName}`,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        loading: false,
      };
    }
    case actionTypes.LOGIN_USER_FAIL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    }
    case actionTypes.LOGOUT_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        userName: null,
        token: null,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        loading: false,
      };
    }
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};
```

HomePage.jsx

```
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const upcomingMoviesSelector = useSelector(state => state.upcomingMovies.items)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUpcomingMoviesAction());
    console.log('')
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <MovieSlider items={upcomingMoviesSelector} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Where do you dispatch the login user action?

Comment: in the login form

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZkY6QJJ and here's the code